# How to add noatime to fstab with script?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to add `noatime` to `fstab` with my bash script that set up my servers.

How do this automatically in a safe way for `/` partition only?

In simple terms:

How to append `,noatime` to the fourth string of a line whose second string is `/` if the line does not already contain `noatime` using bash/shell code?

Example file:

```
# Comment
UUID=1234567890-abcdef    /     ext4  defaults,discard    0    1
UUID=9876543210-fedcdab   /var  ext4  defaults,discard    0    0
```

Need to get:

```
# Comment
UUID=1234567890-abcdef    /     ext4  defaults,discard,noatime    0    1
UUID=9876543210-fedcdab   /var  ext4  defaults,discard    0    0
```

Comment: Note that the `defaults` option is only useful as a filler to make sure the options column isn't empty. It doesn't have any other effect. Thus just `discard` and `defaults,discard` are exactly equivalent.

Comment: If a filesystem is mounted with discard, then deleting files will automatically cause the TRIM command to be issued. This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

This will achieve the desired effect:

```
awk -i inplace '$2 == "/" && !($4 ~ /noatime/) { sub(/[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}[^[:space:]]+/,"&,noatime") }1' /etc/fstab
```

This is a bit more specific than what you asked for — `,noatime` will be added to the fourth field if *that field* doesn’t already contain `noatime`, it doesn’t look at the whole line.

`-i inplace` is Gawk-specific; if it’s not supported, write the result to a new file:

```
awk '$2 == "/" && !($4 ~ /noatime/) { sub(/[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}[^[:space:]]+/,"&,noatime") }1' /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.new && mv /etc/fstab{.new,}
```

In both cases I’m assuming your server setup scripts run as root.

(Thanks to [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) for the robust text substitution avoiding issues with potential regular expressions in the fourth field when using `sub`!)

Comment: It didn't work for me :( my /etc/fstab ```proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# /dev/md/0
UUID=ba14b9c4-70a8-45e4-9819-23d6dc7e1c24 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
# /dev/md/1
UUID=4418b51d-c6ad-4b1d-911d-42adbb3da156 / ext4 defaults 0 0```

Comment: That’s strange, it works for me with that input...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -p -e 'm:^[^#]+\s+/\s+: && ! /noatime/ && s/defaults/$&,noatime/' ./fstab
# Comment
UUID=1234567890-abcdef    /     ext4  defaults,noatime,discard    0    1
UUID=9876543210-fedcdab   /var  ext4  defaults,discard    0    0
```

On lines matching the regex `m:^[^#]+\s+/\s+:`  (i.e. a / surrounded by whitespace that **isn't** preceded by a `#` comment) and not matching `noatime`, it modifies the line to insert `,noatime`.

Note: this inserts `,noatime` after `defaults`, not after `discard`.  IMO that makes more sense because `defaults` is almost certain to be there (more likely than `discard` anyway).

This performs a dry-run, i.e. it does NOT modify `./fstab`, only displays what it would do to stdout.  To make it actually modify the file, use perl's `-i` option:

```
perl -p -i -e 'm:^[^#]+\s+/\s+: && ! /noatime/ && s/defaults/$&,noatime/' ./fstab
```

and, of course, change ./fstab to /etc/fstab.

BTW, if you also want to change any existing instances of `atime`, `relatime`,  `nodiratime`, etc, add a statement to do this **first**.  e.g.

```
perl -p -e 'm:^[^#]+\s+/\s+: && /^[^#]+atime/ && s/([,\s])[^,\s]*atime/noatime/;
  m:^[^#]+\s+/\s+: && ! /noatime/ && s/defaults/$&,noatime/' ./fstab
```

Comment: Yeah, removing `atime, relatime, nodiratime` sounds like a sensible thing to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with GNU sed running in  it's extended regex mode (-E). It will look at
lines whose second field is a lone slash '/' AND the fourth field does not already contain the whole word 'noatime', then it shall append it to the fourth word.

```
sed -E -e '
  \:^\s*\S+\s+/\s:!b
  s/\S+/\n&\n/4
  /\n(.*,)?noatime(,.*)?\n/!s/\n/,noatime/2
  s/\n//g
' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Black voodoo magic :-)